# British driving license from 1991 but living in Germany

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license

I'm a UK national living in Germany with a British driving license from 1991. I can't renew or update my British license (as confirmed by DVLA)  as I don't have an address in Great Britain. However, the old license has no photo, contains my maiden name and my last address in Great Britain. What can I do?

Comment: The logical solution (and what you are supposed to do as far as EU law is concerned) is getting a German license. Is there any reason you can't do that?

Comment: And "getting a German license" means "exchange your British driving license for an equivalent German license".

Comment: @gnasher729 Not only that: Even if the license has expired, was lost or stolen, you are still supposed to get a license in the country where you live. I don't know the specifics for the UK and Germany but I have done it in the Netherlands and the way it works is that you get a document attesting you passed the relevant exam from the country where you first obtained your license and then get a license in the country where you live on the basis of this document. That document is not, in itself, a driving license and also has no photo.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the UK is still part of the EU, your drivers license is valid in Germany for as long as it is valid in the UK. So from the legal site you are fine.
But, as mentioned above, with a European drivers license you have the right to exchange it to a drivers license from the country you moved to (Germany). So with Brexit in mind, maybe it helps to get it changed soon.
For that you can just make an appointment at the Bürgeramt of the city you are living in and bring a biometric photo, your passport, a medical okay from a doctor and a short check up at the eye doctor. The list probably depends on your city and they might have prefilled forms, so check on their website.